# No puedo obtener la ruta real de la SD en mi dispositivo android en Xamarin.forms

Tags: android, c#, xamarin.forms, almacenamiento

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.forms en la cual debo generar un PDF dentro de la tarjeta SD del dispositivo.

El problema que tengo es que cada vez que intento acceder a la SD siempre me devuelve el mismo resultado:

> /storage/emulated/0/HolaMundo.pdf

Esta es la sentencia que utilizo para obtener el directorio... `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;` Si bien es una sentencia que se utiliza solo para android, lo que hice fue crear una clase en el proyecto PCL la cual va a guardar el directorio que obtengo desde el `MainActivity.cs` del proyecto Android.

Como mencioné anteriormente, el directorio que devuelve es una memoria externa emulada, la cual no vendría a ser la SD que tengo físicamente en el dispositivo. Por lo tanto, cada vez que creo un archivo, no puedo encontrarlo en el dispositivo.

Dejo [aquí](https://mega.nz/#!WOxCTSoI!SgnfnsIBMAJ3Koh8-H60IDN6FfyCfldSHOnyamige64) el proyecto para que lo descarguen y lo analicen en caso de que no me haya explicado bien

---

Aquí está el código de cuando obtengo la ruta de la SD

```
 Configuraciones.ExternalPathApp = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path; //Esto devuelve "/storage/emulated/0"
 Configuraciones.PathApp = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); //Esto devuelve "/data/user/0/GenerarPDF.Android/files"
```

Por lo que tengo entendido, a estos directorios solo se pueden acceder en caso de que el dispositivo esté rooteado. En mi caso esta App no va a ser utilizada con dispositivos rooteados

Aquí está el código cuando genero el PDF

```
private void BtnPDF_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Configuraciones.PathApp + "/HolaMundo.pdf";
    string externo = Configuraciones.ExternalPathApp + "/HolaMundo.pdf";

    using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(filename))
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter escritor = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
        doc.AddTitle("HolaMundo");
        doc.AddCreator("Matia Molina");
        doc.Open();
        PdfContentByte contentByte = escritor.DirectContent;
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hola Mundo"));
        doc.Close();
        escritor.Close();
    }

    using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(externo))
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter escritor = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
        doc.AddTitle("HolaMundo");
        doc.AddCreator("Matia Molina");
        doc.Open();
        PdfContentByte contentByte = escritor.DirectContent;
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hola Mundo"));
        doc.Close();
        escritor.Close();
    }

}
```

Probé también creando archivos `.txt`, pero en ningun caso puedo contrar los archivos, ni el PDF ni el TXT.

Comment: Ya está editado, fijate si de eso te sirve, yo compartí el proyecto para que pudieran ver todo en caso de que haya algo que no se entienda.

Comment: Agregaste el permiso de tarjeta SD al manifest?

Comment: Si, fue lo primero que hice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder acceder a la memoria del dispositivo, tenemos los siguientes directorios: "/" es la raíz del dispositivo, "/mnt/sdcard" es la raíz de la memoria interna y "/mnt/sdcard-ext" es la raíz de la memoria externa (SD)... Estos datos tuve que ponerlos a mano desde el MainActivity.cs ya que de otra forma no podía acceder a estos directorios. Esto funciona correctamente ya que desde el MainActivity pude crear una carpeta de prueba.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque yo no guardo los ficheros en el mismo sitio donde los quieres guardar tu, te pongo como lo hago yo a ver si te ayuda.

En el proyecto PCL tengo este interfaz

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Proyecto.Interfaces
{
    public interface IFiles
    {
        void SaveFiles(string filename, byte[] bytes);
    }
}
```

Y en android tengo esta implementación

```
using Android.Content;
using Proyecto.Interfaces;
using Proyecto.Droid.Interfaces;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FilesImplementation))]

namespace Proyecto.Droid.Interfaces
{
    class FilesImplementation : IFiles
    {
        public void SaveFiles(string filename, byte[] bytes)
        {
            var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
            OpenFile(filePath, filename);
        }
     }
   }
```

Cuando quiero grabar un archivo lo hago asi:

```
        var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage);
                if (results.ContainsKey(Permission.Storage))
                       status = results[Permission.Storage];
         }
         if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
         {
                DependencyService.Get<IFiles>().SaveFiles(item.Filename, item.FicheroRaw);
         }
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: El problema con esto es que documentsPath me queda con valor "/data/user/0/GenerarPDF.Android/files"... no importa si cambio el `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` por otra, siempre devuelve el mismo valor